# C# Как установить конкретную кодировку строки?

Tags: c#

У меня есть такая строка `╨Ь╨Р╨Ю ╤В╨╛╨╗╤М╨║╨╛ ╨▓╨┐╨╡╤А╤С╨┤`

Мне нужно перевести ее в кодировку `UTF-8` или любую другую, чтобы текст нормально отображался.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю исходной кодировки этой строки, поэтому я обратился к сервисам.

[**Этот**](https://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru) сервис сообщает, что исходная кодировка - `Windows-1251`

[**Этот**](https://www.online-decoder.com/ru) - `IBM866`.

Но так или иначе, они оба правильно декодировали строку.

---

Я пытался перевести ее в `UTF-8`:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
Encoding srcEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM866");
byte[] srcBytes = srcEncoding.GetBytes(description);
byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.Convert(srcEncoding, utf8, srcBytes);
Console.WriteLine(utf8.GetString(resultBytes));
```

**Выводит: *(тоже самое)***

```
╨Ь╨Р╨Ю ╤В╨╛╨╗╤М╨║╨╛ ╨▓╨┐╨╡╤А╤С╨┤
```

---

Тот же код, но с кодировкой `Windows-1251`

```
Encoding srcEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
```

**Выводит это:**

```
│Ь│Р│Ю TВ│-│┐TМ│││- │-│┐││TАTС│+
```

---

**Как мне в таком случае получить нормальную строку?**

Comment: Проблему нужно решать на другом уровне. Как и откуда вы получили эту строку?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3DZo.png

Comment: @andreymal строку получил из `json`-ответа от другой программы

Comment: вы ее неверно раскодировали, то есть вы показываете строчку в неверной кодировке, то есть это скорее всего строчка в раскодирована с помощью UTF-8, но исходные данные были в другой кодировке. Нужно ее как байты рассматривать и их раскодировать, а не этот текст. Но я попробую.

Comment: Вы можете показать, какой код производит эту строчку? или хотя-бы исходный массив байт до перекодировки дать, хотя-бы в HEX или Base64 формате?

Comment: `json-ответа от другой программы` - из HTTP ответа? Вы делали при старте приложения `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);`? Если это сделать, HttpClient автоматически раскодирует правильно. Что в ответе от сервера в заголовке `Content-Encoding`?

Comment: @aepot текст на русском - "*МАО только вперёд*". Получаю при помощи `System.Diagnostics.Process`, перенаправляя вывод в переменную. Откуда мне получить байты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внезапно, эта строка и так в кодировке была UTF-8, только вот вы ее прочитали с помощью кодировки DOS Codepage-866. Как вам это удалось - не знаю.

```cs
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
// берем символы, полученные с помощью какой-то неизвестной кодировки
// предполагается, что это какая-то двухбайтовая кодировка, а для раскодировки использовалась однобайтовая
string a = "╨Ь╨Р╨Ю ╤В╨╛╨╗╤М╨║╨╛ ╨▓╨┐╨╡╤А╤С╨┤"; 
// предполагаем, что раскодировано с помощью DOS CP866, закодируем обратно
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP866").GetBytes(a);
// предполагаем по характерным двухбайтовым артефактам, что это не английский язык
// а например русский, русские символы в UTF-8 кодируются двумя байтами.
string b = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Вывод в консоль

```
МАО только вперёд
```

Чтобы ломать такие головоломки, разберитесь, что такое кодировки символов, и как они работают.