# Как определить кодировку для корректной записи текста кириллицей в файл на хостинге?

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, кодировка, hosting

Приложение asp.net core 5. Хостинг reg.ru, ОС Windows.

Создаю файл txt на хостинге и пишу в него текст. В тексте есть как латиница, так и кириллица:

```
public static void WriteFile(string str, string path, string nameFile, string typeFile, string newpath)
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectoryInfo newFolder = dirInfo.Parent.CreateSubdirectory(newpath);
        if (!newFolder.Exists)
        {
            newFolder.Create();
        }

        string fullPath = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.{2}", newFolder.FullName, nameFile, typeFile);
        // This text is added only once to the file.
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251")))
                {

                        writer.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, true, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251")))
                {
                        writer.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Латиница и цифры записываются норм, а вот все что кириллицей знаками вопроса - `??????`.
Какую кодировку следует указать для корректной записи текста кириллицей и латиницей?

Попробовал указать UTF8 - не помогло:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath, true, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                   writer.WriteLine(str);
                }
```

Comment: В смысле определить? Вы же сами файл сохраняете - вот с какой кодировкой сохраняете, с той и читайте.

Comment: Попробуйте установить через NuGet ```Install-Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages```. Далее получить ```byte[]``` нужного текста и через цикл (как вот вот тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.codepage?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Encoding_CodePage) получить строку из массива байтов, ну и посмотреть с какой кодировкой читается, а с какой нет.

Comment: Зачем вообще использовать кодировку отличную от utf-8? Особенно если это веб

Comment: А чем вы потом читаете файл и проверяете его кодировку, собственно? Может эта штука, которой вы проверяете, смотрит файл не в той кодировке.

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8` при указании для `StreamWriter` - это UTF-8 с BOM. А надо "без BOM". Чтобы получилось, можно просто не указывать кодировку. По умолчанию используется именно UTF-8 без BOM, ну либо вот так `new UTF8Encoding(false)` вместо `Encoding.UTF8`. Используйте ее и при записи, и при чтении. Еще вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1334466/373567), как верно раскодировать неверно раскодированное. И закопайте 1251 туда, где вы ее откопали. Эта кодировка давно устарела вместе с Windows XP.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо! Оформите в ответ, отмечу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Encoding.UTF8` при указании для `StreamWriter` - это UTF-8 с BOM. А надо "без BOM". Чтобы получилось, можно просто не указывать кодировку. По умолчанию используется именно UTF-8 без BOM, ну либо вот так `new UTF8Encoding(false)` вместо `Encoding.UTF8`. Используйте ее и при записи, и при чтении.

Еще вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1334466/373567), как верно раскодировать неверно раскодированное. И закопайте 1251 туда, где вы ее откопали. Эта кодировка давно устарела вместе с Windows XP.