# Проблема с чтением тела сообщения MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

При чтении тела (самого сообщения) **email** с помощь **MailKit** некорректно читаются некоторые символы. Например **№** превращается в *?*.
Почему-то сообщения приходят с кодировкой **koi8-r**.
При этом если прочитать тело сообщение как *Html*, то там нужный знак есть.
Например в нашем случае ⌀ (№)*.

Читаю сообщения так:

```
var items = inBox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Size | MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.All | MessageSummaryItems.Body | MessageSummaryItems.Full);
foreach(var item in items)
{
   MimeMessage message = inBox.GetMessage(item.UniqueId);
                   
   string from = message.From.Where(x => x is MailboxAddress).Select(x => ((MailboxAddress)x).Name).Aggregate((i, j) => i + ";" + j);
   string emails = message.From.Where(x => x is MailboxAddress).Select(x => ((MailboxAddress)x).Address).Aggregate((i, j) => i + ";" + j);

   string messageText = message.TextBody;
}
```

В message.TextBudy уже текст с кривыми символами.

Была попытка сделать так:

```
      var bodyPart = item.TextBody;
      var body = (TextPart)inBox.GetBodyPart(item.UniqueId, bodyPart);
```

Но там уже стоит charset=koi8-r и кривые символы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, в **Html** теле все в порядке, если его сохранить и открыть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно еще прочитать тело с нормальной кодировкой?

Comment: почему ваш KOI8-R выглядит как криво раскодированный UTF-8? Попробуйте UTF-8.

Comment: @aepot Где я должен это попробовать?
Ответы приходят уже в koi8-r. Если я беру готовый текст, то получаю ?. В HTML можно вручную изменить кодировку, но мне не нужен HTML

Comment: Версия дотнета какая? Операционная система какая?

Comment: @aepot Windows10, тестировалось и на windows server 2016. .NET 5.0
Я не понимаю откуда берется Koi8-r. Само сообщение уже на этапе получения имеет во всех местах именно эту кодировку.
https://imgur.com/a/yDWpbAR

Comment: `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)` - добавьте эту строчку в код, чтобы она выполнилась один раз при старте приложения.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за ответ. Строчка уже стоит в самом начале.

Comment: Ну тогда я сдаюсь.

Comment: Хотя есть еще [вот такие костыли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1334466/373567). Кажется, ваш случай.

Comment: @aepot Не совсем. Похоже, что Koi8-r вообще половину символов не поддерживает, из-за чего еще на этапе чтения письма она читает тот же № как ? и в исходном тексте мы уже видим ?. Т.е я так понимаю нужно читать письмо уже с нужной кодировкой

Comment: Вы сначала попробуйте перекостылить кодировку так чтобы русский текст отображался корректно, чтобы точно убедиться, что есть потеря данных. Может это просто отладчик так показывает. Но знака № и правда нет в KOI-8R, то есть здесь безвыходная ситуация. Вообще эта кодировка устаревшая и давно не используется в письмах.